# Samsung tablet blocked

Tags: samsung, downloading

Bonjour,
Tout à l'heure j'ai ressortis ma tablette samsung a6 pour tester une nouvelle fonctionnalité de steam. En voulant l'allumer, j'ai eu un écran bleu avec écris "downloading". J'ai vu sur plusieurs forum qu'il fallait la mettre en mode recovery jusqu'au redémarrage de l'appareil, ce que j'ai fait. Seulement, j'ai malencontreusement relâché les boutons. Ce qui fait que mon appareil est bloqué, je n'arrive pas à le redémarrer. Est-ce un problème de chargeur? Ou un problème de l'appareil ?
Merci de m'aider,
Ziscko.

Hello !
I try to retart my tablet samsung a6, but a blue screen apears with "downlading".
I learn in others forums that i have to restar my tablet in recovery mode, but i failed it and sneeze at bad moment: i didn't recovery mode until restaring.
Sorry for ma very bad english..
Can somebody help me ?

*Translated using Google Translate:*

Hello, Just now I came out my Samsung A6 tablet to test a new feature of steam. Wanting to turn it on, I had a blue screen with "downloading". I saw on several forums that it was necessary to put in recovery mode until restarting the device, which I did. Only, I accidentally released the buttons. What makes my device is blocked, I can not restart it. Is it a charger problem? Or a problem of the device? Thanks for helping me, Ziscko.

Answer (score 0):

download mode is to install firmware or custom recovery. It's accessible VIA pressing power button and vol- button at the same time do if it boots all time to download maybe your vol- button is broken. Also if you want to enter recovery turn device off by holding power button or power+vol- buttons and when it's turned off hold vol+ and power to enter recovery. At recovery you should see "reboot to system option.